# TapGesturecognizer not working in backgroundview in iphone X 12.1

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple code to add tapgestureRecognizer to dismis ViewController when tap in screen, but it not working only in iPhone X 12.1.

```
addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeSharing(_:))))
```

Note: magicaly, when i add tap gesturecognizer to a new view that constraint equal to view that also not working, but if i constraint the new view not equal to view, that working. Does any one know why?.

Comment: Where do you add Tap gesture?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, i test to add it in interface builder but it also not working too

Comment: thank you, now it working, i don't know why but maybe my xcode or my simulator get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check a couple of things here:

**First step** make sure that your main view is not covered for example of another top view which will break your tap gesture, so add the gesture to your top view.

**Second step** Make sure your view that will have the gesture should have the property `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`, otherwise the gesture will not work.

**Third step** Make sure your view appears when your testing, you might have a problem with constraints, so the view is out of screen bounds, so try giving the view a `backgroundColor = .red` to see if it exists or not, or you can use **View Debugger** from xCode.

Example of a working gesture:

```
    let viewToDismiss = UIView(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
    viewToDismiss.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeSharing(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    viewToDismiss.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but i had checked all of this, and it still not working in only iphoneX 12.1 simulator.

Comment: thank you, now it working, i don't know why but maybe my xcode or my simulator get error.